# Need Help Implementing Multi-Segment Matching With PCRE2 in C++

Tags: c++, partial, pcre2

I am trying to implement [multi-segment matching with `pcre2_match`](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2partial.html#SEC4) in accordance with the documentation.

```cpp
// #define PCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH 0
// #include <pcre2.h>

// Variable initialisation
char const *string_one = "one ";
char const *string_two = "one hundred";
int        error_number; // <- These are unused in
PCRE2_SIZE error_offset; //    our example.
int return_code;
auto *code = pcre2_compile_8((PCRE2_SPTR8) "one hundred",
                             PCRE2_ZERO_TERMINATED,
                             0,
                             &error_number,
                             &error_offset,
                             NULL);
if (code == NULL) { fprintf(stderr, "`pcre2_compile`"); exit(1); }
auto *match_data = pcre2_match_data_create_from_pattern_8(code, NULL);
auto *ovector    = pcre2_get_ovector_pointer_8(match_data);

// Matching
return_code = pcre2_match_8(code,
                            (PCRE2_SPTR8) string_one,
                            PCRE2_ZERO_TERMINATED,
                            0,
                            PCRE2_PARTIAL_HARD,
                            match_data,
                            NULL);
if (return_code == PCRE2_ERROR_PARTIAL) {
  PCRE2_SIZE offset = ovector[1]; // Positions [0] and [1] designate the
                                  // bounds of the first match.
  return_code = pcre2_match_8(code,
                             (PCRE2_SPTR8) string_two,
                             PCRE2_ZERO_TERMINATED,
                             offset,
                             PCRE2_PARTIAL_HARD | PCRE2_NOTBOL,
                             match_data,
                             NULL);
  printf("[rc]: %d\n", return_code);
}
```

We compile the regular expression `/one hundred/` and declare two strings to match against (`string_one` and `string_two`). According to the documentation, once a partial match has been produced, you append the next segment to the first one and call `pcre2_match` with an offset, so we prepare `string_two` as though it was the first string followed by the next set of data.

1. We match the compiled regex `code` against `string_one` using the option `PCRE_PARTIAL_HARD`, expecting a partial match. This, indeed, sets `return_code` to `-2` (`PCRE2_ERROR_PARTIAL`), telling us the match is incomplete (or, rather, to my understanding, might be incomplete, which in this case definitely is true).
2. Knowing the match was only partial, we retrieve the ending bound of the partial match from the `ovector` (this is verified as `4`), and match against an initially identical string followed by the characters required for a complete match. `PCRE2_NOTBOL` (not beginning of line) is specified here withal in accordance with the documentation.

I expect `return_code` following the second call to `pcre2_match` to take on a non-negative value (or possibly `-2` if I have misunderstood something). Instead, `-1` is returned, denoting `PCRE2_ERROR_NOMATCH`.

Why is that?

Comment: The offset is supposed to be to where the partial match started, not to where it ended. In your example, that would be 0.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I assumed multi-segment matching wouldn't require re-matching the matched partial, but I realise that's the case as per your comment. Is there an alternate way to handle matching against multi-segmented data more efficiently, or is this what we must live with?

Comment: I only know what's on the documentation page you cited. The example they show passes the starting offset of the partial match. If there was a more efficient method, one would imagine the documentation would mention it.

Comment: It seems [MULTI-SEGMENT MATCHING WITH pcre2_dfa_match()](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2partial.html#SEC6) behaves the way you expected - you just pass a second segment (not a concatenation of first and second) and it picks up exactly where the previous call left off.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you! I ended up using `pcre2_dfa_match` instead and it works like a charm where I needed it.